# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de fondo en una celda?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, css

Llevo un tiempo dando vueltas y no soy capaz de dar con la solucion, a ver si me podeis ayudar. He intentado hacer busquedas en la web, pero no encuentro lo que necesito.

Os explico. 
Tengo una tabla (.php), la tabla obtiene los valores mediante una consulta a mysql.
Hasta aqui funciona correctamente.

Lo que necesito es que mediante css, js o lo que se os ocurra, en una de las columnas (ciudad), las celdas tengan un color diferente dependiendo de la ciudad que figure. Por ejemplo:
Si el resultado de la consulta en esa celda es Madrid, el fondo sea rojo, si el resultado es Cordoba, sea azul y asi sucesivamente.

```
<?php
require_once 'connection_simple_tareas.php';
$result;

$conn = dbConnect();
// Create the query
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tareas ORDER BY id desc';
// Create the query and asign the result to a variable call $result
$result = $conn->query($sql);
// Extract the values from $result
$rows = $result->fetchAll();
// Since the values are an associative array we use foreach to extract the values from $rows
```

?>

```
</head>
<body>

    <table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Fecha entrada</th>
            <th>Ticket</th>
            <th>Ciudad</th>
            <th>Tipo</th>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Comentarios</th>
            <th>Direccion</th>
            <th>Nodo</th>
            <th>Tecnico</th>
            <th>Fecha cierre</th>
            <th>Solucion</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['fecha_entrada']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ticket']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ciudad']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['tipo']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['titulo']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['comentarios']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['direccion']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['nodo']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['tecnico']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['fecha_cierre']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['solucion']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola amigo, podrias colocar el codigo que llevas hecho hasta el momento

Comment: como puedo insertar el codigo??

Comment: Edita tu pregunta al momento de editarla te saldra una obcion asi "{ }" esa es la opcion de insertar codigo

Comment: Ahora no tengo aqui a mano el codigo para copiar y pegar, lo pongo de cabeza

Comment: Primero se lanza la consulta a la base de datos
Tras obtenerla están definidos los encabezados de las columnas con sus respectivo <th> xxxx</th>
Y luego se rellenan las celdas con este código para cada celda de cada columna
<td><?php echo $row [‘ciudad’];  ? ><td>

Comment: Si el estilo es tan dependiente del valor de la ciudad, puedes añadir un campo a la tabla `tareas`  con el código del color e inyectarle el estilo directamente sobre el elemento tal que `<td style="background-color: <?php echo $row['color']; ?>"><?php echo $row['ciudad']; ?></td>`

Comment: Se eliminó la etiqueta "background" Más detalles en [¿Qué uso le damos a la etiqueta \[background\]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2060/65)

Answer (score 4):

Para elegir el color de fondo en CSS se usa "background-color", aplicalo a la celda  que quieras.
Por ejemplo:

```html
<table>
<tr><td>celda 1<td style="background-color:salmon">celda 2
<tr><td>celda 3<td>celda 4
</table>
```

En tu caso particular, busca en el código PHP donde crea la tabla HTML y añade un class a los  que creas oportuno, usa una matriz con los possibles resultados que quieras colorear y el nombre de la class a assignar, por ejemplo:

```css
.fondo_salmon {background-color: salmon;}
.fondo_verde {background-color: lightgreen;}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Celda 1<td class=fondo_salmon>Celda 2
<tr><td class=fondo_verde>Celda 3<td>Celda 4
</table>
```

Otra posible solución, seria ir asignando un color a las celdas según el contenido de manera automática, guardando en un array los valores aparecidos.
Un ejemplo en JS, así se ve el resultado.

```js
 var listaTD=IDlista.getElementsByTagName("TD"); //lista de <TD> de la tabla "IDlista"
 var valoresTD=[]; // Lista de valores, sin repetir.
 var coloresTD=[]; // id de color assignado a cada valor.
 var colores=["lightyellow","lightgreen","lightblue","salmon"];
 var colorIndice=0; // indice de color
 var i; // guardará el indice del valor encontrado/guardado.
 for (let td=0; td<listaTD.length; td++) {
    // Busca el valor del TD actual en la matriz de control
  i=valoresTD.findIndex(function(valor){return valor==listaTD[td].innerHTML});
  if (i==-1) { // Si no lo encuentra, lo guarda y assigna color
   valoresTD.push(listaTD[td].innerHTML);
   i=valoresTD.length-1;
   coloresTD.push(colorIndice++);
   if (colorIndice>=colores.length) colorIndice=0;
  }
    // Assigna el color de fondo.
  listaTD[td].style.backgroundColor=colores[coloresTD[i]];
 }
```

```html
<table id=IDlista>
<tr><td>Celda 1</td><td>Celda 2</td>
<tr><td>Celda 3</td><td>Celda 4</td>
<tr><td>Celda 2</td><td>Celda 4</td>
<tr><td>Celda 3</td><td>Celda 1</td>
</table>
```

La idea es introducir tantos colores como valores distintos haya, si hay menos volverá a empezar la lista de colores.

En tu caso particular, si solo quieres colorear una columna, usa un class para identidicarlas, el script deberia ser algo parecido a esto...

```js
 var listaTD=tabla1.getElementsByClassName("autoColor");
 var valoresTD=[];
 var coloresTD=[];
 var colores=["lightyellow","lightgreen","lightblue","salmon"];
 var colorIndice=0;
 var i;
 for (let td=0; td<listaTD.length; td++) {
  i=valoresTD.findIndex(function(valor){return valor==listaTD[td].innerHTML});
  if (i==-1) {
   valoresTD.push(listaTD[td].innerHTML);
   i=valoresTD.length-1;
   coloresTD.push(colorIndice++);
   if (colorIndice>=colores.length) colorIndice=0;
  }
  listaTD[td].style.backgroundColor=colores[coloresTD[i]];
 }
```

```html
    <table border="1" id="tabla1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Fecha entrada</th>
            <th>Ticket</th>
            <th>Ciudad</th>
            <th>Tipo</th>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Comentarios</th>
            <th>Direccion</th>
            <th>Nodo</th>
            <th>Tecnico</th>
            <th>Fecha cierre</th>
            <th>Solucion</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>id1</td>
            <td>fecha1</td>
            <td>ticket1</td>
            <td class="autoColor">ciudad1</td>
            <td>tip1o</td>
            <td>titulo1</td>
            <td>comentarios1</td>
            <td>direccion1</td>
            <td>nodo1</td>
            <td>tecnico1</td>
            <td>cierre1</td>
            <td>solucion1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>id2</td>
            <td>fecha2</td>
            <td>ticket2</td>
            <td class="autoColor">ciudad2</td>
            <td>tipo2</td>
            <td>titulo2</td>
            <td>comentarios2</td>
            <td>direccion2</td>
            <td>nodo2</td>
            <td>tecnico2</td>
            <td>cierre2</td>
            <td>solucion2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>id3</td>
            <td>fecha3</td>
            <td>ticket3</td>
            <td class="autoColor">ciudad1</td>
            <td>tipo3</td>
            <td>titulo3</td>
            <td>comentarios3</td>
            <td>direccion3</td>
            <td>nodo3</td>
            <td>tecnico3</td>
            <td>cierre3</td>
            <td>solucion3</td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>id4</td>
            <td>fecha4</td>
            <td>ticket4</td>
            <td class="autoColor">ciudad3</td>
            <td>tipo4</td>
            <td>titulo4</td>
            <td>comentarios4</td>
            <td>direccion4</td>
            <td>nodo4</td>
            <td>tecnico4</td>
            <td>cierre4</td>
            <td>solucion4</td>
        </tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

La idea se puede adaptar a PHP sin problemas, he usado JS para que se vea el resultado.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, pero eso no me sirve, las celdas se rellenan desde una consulta a base de datos y no puedes predecir el valor que va a tener cada celda

Comment: la idea es que dependiendo del resultado de la consulta, el fondo cambie a un color u otro

Comment: Crea un Array con los distintos resultados que quieras colorear y su color correspondiente (color CSS o nombre de class a aplicar) y cada vez que ponga un <TD> busca el valor en el array y si está le aplicas el color (o class) que corresponda.

Comment: Creo que eso no me sirve. los datos que hay en cada celda son aleatorios, tendria que hacerse de una forma que el codigo "leyera" el texto y dependiendo de lo que fuera, aplicara un fondo un otro, lo mismo que se hace en excel con el formato condicional. algo asi como lo de esta imagen http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_9714662captura.png

Comment: lo del array me puede cuadran, me lo podrias explicar un poco mas

Comment: Te he puesto otra solución en JS.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho el interes, pero me pierdo. En mi primer mensaje he puesto el codigo que estoy utilizando para la rellenar la tabla. Como cuadraria lo que me dices con lo que yo uso??

Comment: Es solo un ejemplo, se debería adaptar la idea, en tu caso solo modificaría una columna en concreto.
Para adaptarlo debería poner una class a las celdas de ciudad y en el script hacer un getElementsByClassname y ejecutar el script despues de cerrar la tabla.

Comment: Te he dejado otro ejemplo.

Comment: Lo que te voy a comentar ahora, lo digo de oidas, hace tiempo que no toco SQL... una manera mas "elegante" seria preguntar al SQL que celdas tienen cierto valor, y elegir color para esas celdas, La gracia seria que no tendrías que crear ninguna matriz, ahorrando memoria y proceso.
Si no hay "muchos" valores distintos no creo que valga la pena.

Answer (score 3):

No es una buena idea meter css "inline". Es mejor añadir una clase, por ejemplo ".green" en tu hoja de estilos, y la clase correspondiente en la tabla.

Además es mucho más claro y mantenible si lo metes en un array. Así si cambias un color, no tienes que rebuscar en el código, y puedes reutilizar las clases en otras partes de tu programa. Quedaría así:

```
    PHP:
    <?php 
    $arr_ciudades_colores = array(
            'madrid' => 'green', 
            'barcelona' => 'blue'
    );
    ?>

    ............

    HTML:
    <tr>
            <td class="<?php echo $arr_ciudades_colores[ $row['ciudad'] ];?>">
                    <?php echo $row['ciudad']; ?>
            </td>
    </tr>

    ............

    CSS:
    .green{background: green; // puedes sustituir green por su código en hexadecimal}
    .blue{background: blue;}
```

Espero que te sirva :)

Comment: ok, gracias, me lo miro

Comment: justo tenía en mente algo muy parecido :D

Comment: Buena solución, asegúrate de rellenar la lista con todas las ciudades y que estén escritas igual que en la base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que necesitas es cambiar el color de la celda dependiendo del resultado de tu consulta podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php

$ciudad = ["Loja","Quito","Guayaquil" ]; //datos a mostrar en la tabla

$tabla = "<table>";
$tabla .= "<thead>";
$tabla .= "<tr>";
$tabla .= "<th>Ciudad</th>";
$tabla .= "</tr>";
$tabla .= "</thead>";
$tabla .= "<tbody>";
foreach($ciudad as $clave => $valor){ //Recorres los resultado de tu consulta y compruebas el valor de la celda que quieres colorear
    $tabla .= "<tr>";
    switch($valor){
        case "Loja";
            $tabla .= "<td bgcolor='#FF0000'>$valor</td>";
            break;
        default:
            $tabla .= "<td>$valor</td>";
            break;
    }

    $tabla .= "</tr>";
}
$tabla .= "</tbody>";
$tabla .= "</table>";

echo $tabla;
```

Compruebas el valor de tu consulta y cambias el color con el atributo bgcolor, en este caso uso `switch` ya que puedes comprobar algunos valores, si solo es uno podriías usar un condicional `if`

**EDIT**

En base al código que has puesto, lo que podrías hacer es lo siguiente:

Antes de imprimir el valor de ciudad, compara el valor y luego imprimes la celda.

Actualmente tienes esto:

```
<td><?php echo $row['ciudad']; ?></td>
```

Podrías hacer algo como:

```
<?php 

switch($row['ciudad']){
  case 'Madrid':
    echo "<td bgcolor='#FF0000'>$row[ciudad]</td>";
    break;
  case 'Barcelona':
    echo "<td bgcolor='#00FF00'>$row[ciudad]</td>";
    break;
  default:
    echo "<td>$row[ciudad]</td>";
    break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Lo que tendria que comprobar es unicamente el valos de los <td> de una columna

Comment: Pero con tanto codigo me pierdo

Comment: Con un if como seria??

Comment: En cualquier caso debes recorrer los resultados de tu consulta, si necesitas comprobar un solo valor podrías usar if, de lo contrario deberías  anidar ifs y el código se haría un poco ilegible, en ese caso es mejor usar switch, te pongo ese ejemplo ya que no esta el código que tu has hecho, y no sabria como estas trayendo los datos desde la db, la logica es recorrer tu consulta, y cuando llegue a la columna ciudad comparas el valor y cambias el color.

Comment: A ver si soy capaz de pegar el codigo, ya estoy en mi ordenador

Comment: ya esta añadido en el primer mensaje del hilo

Comment: No se porque ha salido partido en 2, pero va todo del tiron en el .php

Comment: @paco acabo de editar la respuesta, revisala a ver si te sirve.

Comment: leyendolo por encima me podria cuadrar, lo que no se es en que punto del .php meterlo. Porque yo lo que tengo es el resultado de una consulta dentro de 2 td.  Tendria que poner todo ese codigo dentro de los td??

Comment: cambia  la fila que te menciono `<td><?php echo $row['ciudad']; ?></td>
`, por todo el código que te propongo y deberia funcionarte sin problema.

Comment: entiendo, seria <td> tu codigo </td>   es asi lo que me quieres decir

Comment: No, es que en el codigo igual estas imprimiendo un <td>, quita toda esa linea, y coloca el codigo propuesto

Comment: ok, mañana lo pruebo y te digo. muchas gracias

Comment: PERFECTO con estas ultimas instrucciones funcionando a la perfeccion. Unicamente faltaba ?> al final del codigo

Comment: MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS